# Multiple LAN interfaces on SonicWALL

Tags: dell

We have a SonicWALL 2400. Is there any way to assign multiple interfaces to the same LAN subnet?

Basically, we would like to have X1 for the WAN and X0, X2, X3 and X4 connected to 4 devices that would form a LAN.

Due to limited space, we are unable to add a switch to do this.

Comment: It would help if you also gave a brief explanation of why you want to do this. (For example, why not just hang an ethernet switch of one of the LAN interfaces and hang your other devices off the switch?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible using the Firewall model specified in the question.

The final solution was to get more space to add a switch behind the firewall.

Comment: I have the same issue, whilst the portshield option is available on the tz210 model it is not available on the n2400

Answer (score 4):

Yes, The SonicWALL does this by default.

Go through the Setup Wizard and you can select the radio-button for the setup where X1 is WAN and all other ports are set to the LAN Zone.  You can also do two WAN interfaces and the rest to the LAN.  These are the options available in the Setup Wizard, but if you want to change more granuarly you can simply go to each interface and assign it to the appropriate Zone.

Set your other three ports to LAN zone and the SonicWALL will switch all ports in that zone.

Comment: This is exactly what we're using on our old sonicwall appliance. However there's no such option in the wizard. As for setting them manually, the only way it can be done is by assigning different subnets to the different interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

When assigning the Port, set the zone to LAN or whichever subnet you want to share with and then for mode, choose "PortShield Switch Mode". It will then give you the option of a port (X0 for instance) to link to. Now your new port is a switch port connected to the X0 LAN.